# Want to add Title and Date in listview through database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to add Task title and Date in the `ListView` but using following code it only shows Date (from COLUMN_DATE) and doesn't show title at all. The title is not loading, but date is being loaded.

```
private void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> taskList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID,
                    TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE,
                    TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
                    },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
        int idx1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE);
        taskList1.add(cursor.getString(idx1));

    }

    if   (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_todo, R.id.task_title, taskList);
        mAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_todo, R.id.dateTextView, taskList1);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mTaskListView1.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
    }
    else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: you need to debug if task is available inside the database and it is properly fetched

Comment: If i remove this line, it loads task but not date.mTaskListView1.setAdapter(mAdapter1);

Comment: After line `int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);` add line `Log.d("DBTITLE","Title extracted from Cursor = " + cursor.getString(idx) + " for Row " + cursor.getPosition());` then look at the log. If title is appearing then your issue is with the listview, otherwise data is likely  not being extracted perhaps because it doesn't exist or doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: It is appearing in the log, the problem is with this  mTaskListView1.setAdapter(mAdapter1); This overwrites the mTaskListView value with the date. If i remove this line then i dont get Date but Task_Title is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are using the same layout, which will have the same id's and there is nothing to differentiate between which is to be used (*probably not actually true as it's likely first come first served, but the end results will be confusing*).

*Perhaps imagine having identical twins both called Fred*

I'd suggest having two layouts with unique id's e.g. have another layout called **`item_todo1`** with id's **`task_title1`** and **`dateTextView1`**.

and then replace

`mAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_todo, R.id.dateTextView, taskList1);`

with (i.e. use the 2nd layout with the other id)

`mAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_todo1, R.id.dateTextView1, taskList1);`

You will also need to get the id for `dateTextView1` and perhaps `task_title`.

*Note! this assumes that you want to have the 2 ListViews, it may be that you think you need 2*

Perhaps what you want is a single list showing both the Date and the Title in which case the following will probably work, which is perhaps the simplest solution (I think I understand why you have 2 lists and that it is due to the complexities of having multiple items).

This method will use the Cursor directly via a **`SimpleCursorAdapter`** as opposed to an **`ArrayAdapter`**, which not only does away with the need for intermediate Arrays but more easily copes with multiple elements within a list item. The only drawback (if even a drawback) is that the Cursor remains and MUST remain open and thus the Database must also be kept open (solution is to close in the activty's `onDestroy` method).

The full code (tested) bar the DBHelper (noting that this also generates some rows for testing) is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    DBHelper mDBHelper;
    Cursor mCursor;
    ListView mTaskListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getDB();
        mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tasklistview);

        // Add some tasks for testing
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            mDBHelper.addRow("TITLE" + String.format("%03d", i), Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
        UpdateUI();
    }

    private void UpdateUI() {

        mCursor = mDB.query(DBHelper.TBNAME,
                new String[]{"rowid AS _id", DBHelper.COL_TASK_TITLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_todo, mCursor,
                new String[]{DBHelper.COL_TASK_TITLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE},
                new int[]{R.id.task_title, R.id.date_textView},
                0
        );

        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

#### Adapting the above code (note untested so may have typos)

You only need to consider the **`UpdateUI`** method which would need to be tailored would be (not tested and hence there may be typos) :-

```
private void UpdateUI() {

            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID,
                    TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE,
                    TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
                    },
            null, null, null, null, null);
            mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.item_todo, 
                mCursor,
                // Displayed data source column names                
                new String[]{
                    TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, 
                    TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE},
                // respective layout id's for the displayed data
                new int[]{
                    R.id.task_title, 
                    R.id.date_textView},
                    0
            );

            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
```

**NOTE!!!** column **`_id`** is required by cursor adapters, if for example you the column name equated to **ID** (no underscore prefix) then the App would fail. Solutions use 'ID AS _id' in the query or `rowid AS _id` or change the column name permanently.

#### Other considerations :-

Here's some code (tested but not adapted, so using my testing code) to show another advantage of Cursor adpater, the ease of performing actions against the database (in these example deleting rows) :-

```
private void implementListViewListener() {

    // ONITEMCLICK LISTENER
    mTaskListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // DO YOUR ONCLICK STUFF HERE
            // NOTE l is the _id of the row e.g. to delete a task
            mDB.delete(DBHelper.TBNAME,DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?",new String[]{Long.toString(l)});
            // To then refresh the ListView
            // a) get the refreshed data(Cursor) from the database
            mCursor = mDB.query(DBHelper.TBNAME,
                    new String[]{"rowid AS _id", DBHelper.COL_TASK_TITLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
            mAdapter.swapCursor(mCursor);
        }
    });

    // ONITEMLONGCLICK LISTENER (NOTE returns boolean should very likely/mostly return TRUE)
    mTaskListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // DO YOUR ONCLICK STUFF HERE
            // NOTE l is the _id of the row e.g. to delete a task
            mDB.delete(DBHelper.TBNAME,DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?",new String[]{Long.toString(l)});
            // To then refresh the ListView
            // a) get the refreshed data(Cursor) from the database
            mCursor = mDB.query(DBHelper.TBNAME,
                    new String[]{"rowid AS _id", DBHelper.COL_TASK_TITLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
            mAdapter.swapCursor(mCursor);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

To use the above you'd just have to code `implementListViewListener();` in the activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and detailed explanation, it did worked as you said.